# LINQ with EF6: Losing second reference in two column table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a strange problem here.

In my database, I have a table called "NeighbourCountry":
It consists of a source country, and an associated neighbour country.

```
public class NeighbourCountry
    {
        [Key]
        public int NeighbourCountryID { get; set; }

        public Country Source { get; set; }

        public Country Neighbour { get; set; }
    }
```

It is filled like this pattern:

```
source_a,neighbour_x
source_a,neighbour_u
source_a,neighbour_t
source_b,neighbour_n
source b,neighbour_p
```

Now I just wanted to get the neighbours of one country with a simple method:
(For easier debugging, I just try to get only the **FIRST** neighbour of a country)

```
private string GetNeighbours(ApplicationDbContext context, Country paracountry)
        {
            var neighbours = context.NeighbourCountries.Where(b => b.Source.CountryID == paracountry.CountryID).FirstOrDefault();
            return "";
        }
```

And now, when I hover over "neighbours", I get this:
[image]

As you can see, it does find the source country, but says there is no neighbour to it.
That is not correct, the database is filled with this data:

[image]

The source country in this case is the country with the ID 1.
In the database, the country with ID 1 is listed correctly with its neighbours.

Now comes the even stranger part:
When I try it the other way round, LINQing to the neighbour directly instead to the source, I get the same scenario, just the other way round.

```
var neighbours = context.NeighbourCountries.Where(b => b.Neighbour.CountryID == paracountry.CountryID).FirstOrDefault();
```

As I said, then I get this:
[image]

So Linq DOES find this neighbour, but now it can't find the first associated source country.
I seems like it can't connect source country and neighbour country.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a problem of lazy loading I would say.

If you want to retrieve Neighbour and Source, eager load them, using Include

```
context.NeighbourCountries
         .Include(m => m.Neighbour)
         .Include(m => m.Source)
         .Where(b => b.Neighbour.CountryID == paracountry.CountryID).FirstOrDefault();
```

(In fact,  you don't need to include the related entity which is in the where clause, but that makes maybe things clearer).

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you so much! I don't understand what's going on here, and why this is working... but thank you :D

Comment: try to goole for "lazy loading" and "eager loading" to understand, it will help ;)